# Get combinations of a list of number in a sequence

Tags: python

Hi I am working with python. I am working with a list of numbers

```
A = [7,9,6,8]
```

I want to get the permutations of the numbers that are in a sequential manner. Desired output is as below:

```
[(6), (7), (8), (9), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9)]
```

My code is as below:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> A = [6,8,7,9]
>>> def comb(myc: list):
        retcol = []
        for i in range(1,len(myc)):
            retcol += list(itertools.combinations(myc,i))
        return retcol

>>> S = sorted(A, key=int)
>>> comb(S)
[(6,), (7,), (8,), (9,), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 9), (6, 7, 8), (6, 7, 9), (6, 8, 9), (7, 8, 9)]
>>> 

[(6,), (7,), (8,), (9,), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 9), (6, 7, 8), (6, 7, 9), (6, 8, 9), (7, 8, 9)]
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I get only the combinations that are in a sequence like shown in the desired output above.
2. Is there a better way to get such kinda result without putting in an explicit `for loop`? maybe a `list comprehension`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
l = sorted(A)
[l[j : j + i] for i in range(1, len(l)) for j in range(len(l) - i + 1)]
```

This yields

```
[[6], [7], [8], [9], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]
```

which isn't quite what you asked for, but I'm guessing you just made mistakes (e.g., having the first element be a bare number instead of a one-element tuple or one-element list).

Comment: Brilliant, can't quite wrap my head around how that works but if OP wanted to stick with tuples he can also use: `sorted((tuple(A[i : j]) for i in range(len(A)) for j in range(len(A) + 1) if j > i), key = len)`.  But of course the single tuples will still show as `(x,)`.

Comment: @Kodiologist  there is an error in the question sorry, the A is not a list it's a set. Because of which you get the output as a tuple itself. just a quick question through, when I convert the set to a list and then use your function the order is reversed e.g. [7,6] [8,7,6] etc.. any idea how can I avoid that?

Comment: @iam.Carrot Try sorting `A` first. I've made the edit above.

Comment: @iam.Carrot You're welcome. I also thought of a tweak that allows you to avoid the outermost `sorted`, so I made that.

Comment: @Kodiologist  yeah I figured, but I am not quite sure how is this code working.

Comment: @Kodiologist the provided answer isn't working for if `A = [5, 6, 8, 9]` any idea how would it work

Comment: @iam.Carrot What do you mean "isn't working"? It produces `[[5], [6], [8], [9], [5, 6], [6, 8], [8, 9], [5, 6, 8], [6, 8, 9]]`. Isn't that what you want?